# I get no hits in the response

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The NEST client send the a request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/product/_search?typed_keys=true
```

and this doesn't return any results.

But if I send a HTTP request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?typed_keys=true
```

then I get results. Why is this? Have I indexed something wrong?

**NEST version:** 6.0.2

**Elasticsearch version:** 6.2.3

Comment: Have you try request http://localhost:9200/myindex/product/_search

Comment: @ThanhLD I did. No results. If I remove /product then I get the results. /myindex represents the name of my index. What is the /product represent? The document type in my index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out. In case someone should have the same problem in the future.

When I was indexing my documents, the "model" name was "producthomepagemodel" but in the application in which I query the index I use the model "product". These models have the same properties but the class name is different. It works now.

Comment: You can map a different `_type` name to a POCO with `DefaultMappingFor<T>(...)` and `.TypeName(...)` on ConnectionSettings: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html#_options_on_connectionsettings